# Create view with sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql, view

I know `mysql` doesn't support `subquery` within a `view`. 
I'm developing a role base application which has a complex `query` for a particular result set. I'm able to build the result set. Now I want to make a view with the result set. 
Sql Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52777/1

**One way around is known to me**: make `view` for each sub query and I don't like it.
Is there any way to make a view with this result set.
The result set would be.

`app_user.id` **|** `role.id` (, seperated if multiple) **|** `action.id` (, seperated if multiple)

**Logic**: 2nd column is based on `user_role` and 3rd column is based on `role_action` / `action.is_anonymous` = `true`

Again, I already build the result set. Can it be re-written to create a view with a single query.

Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to optimize the `query` and thought I'd share. The result set is same with no `subquery` and and I finally created a `view` with it. 
SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52777/26

```
SELECT au.id user_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ur.role_id) role_ids,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ac.id) action_ids
FROM
app_user AS au
LEFT JOIN user_role AS ur ON au.id = ur.user_id
LEFT JOIN role_action AS ra ON ra.role_id = ur.role_id
LEFT JOIN action AS ac ON ac.id = ra.action_id OR ac.is_anonymous = TRUE
GROUP BY au.id
```